# Angular subscribe next is not assigning data to public variable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm calling this in the in the ngOnInit and I have made a variable `userData` public:

```
public userData: User;

ngOnInit () {
    ...
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe({
      next (userServiceData) {
        this.userData = userServiceData
      },
      error (err) {
        this.errorMessage = err
      },
      complete () {
        if (!this.userData.aTypeOfUser) {
          this.pdfValue = '/Content/aTypeOfUser.pdf';
        } else if (this.userData.bTypeOfUser) {
          this.pdfValue = '/Content/bTypeOfUser.pdf';
        } else {
          this.pdfValue = '/Content/cTypeOfUser.pdf';
        }
      }
    });
}
```

When I do a breakpoint inside the `complete ()` - I see data in this.userData - however, if I put a `console.log(this.userData, 'userData');` outside of the entire `subscribe` method

**this.userData is NULL**

What am I missing in the assignment in the next?  It doesn't appear to be assigned the public variable anything.

Comment: can you try to put a console.log(this) to make sure that 'this' is what do you think is 'this'

Comment: if you use instead of functions  userServiceData => this.userData = userServiceData that can help

Comment: `however, if I put a console.log(this.userData, 'userData'); outside of the entire subscribe method` If it's outside, then it's going to be executing synchronously, before the `next` happens (i'm assuming getUser is asynchronous). Why are you putting the log outside?

Answer (score 0):

I meen

```
ngOnInit () {
...
this.userService.getUser().subscribe(
  userServiceData =>
    this.userData = userServiceData
  ,
  err =>
    this.errorMessage = err
  ,
  () => {
    if (!this.userData.aTypeOfUser) {
      this.pdfValue = '/Content/aTypeOfUser.pdf';
    } else if (this.userData.bTypeOfUser) {
      this.pdfValue = '/Content/bTypeOfUser.pdf';
    } else {
      this.pdfValue = '/Content/cTypeOfUser.pdf';
    }
  }
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> if I put a console.log(this.userData, 'userData'); outside of the entire > subscribe method this.userData is NULL

That is **exactly** the expected behavior. You should see either `null` or `undefined` if you are trying to use a variable that is supposed to store data within the `subscribe`.

> What am I missing

`Observables` handle **asynchronous** code when you subscribe to them:

```js
userName!: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myService.getName().subscribe((name) => {
    this.userName = name;
    console.log('1) user name: ', this.userName);
  });
  
  console.log('2) user name: ', this.userName);
}

// 2) user name: undefined
// 1) user name: 'Mike'
```

If you want to use `userData`, you should handle it within the `subscribe` instance, or you could use it later when you need to. `Observables` are **lazy** by default, only when you `subscribe` to them, you'll get the data, otherwise, you don't.

```js
userName$!: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  // storing it for later
  this.userName$ = this.myService.getName();
}

onClick(): void {
  // when a button clicks
  this.userName$.subscribe((name) => console.log('My name is: ', name));
}
```

Or better yet, you can subscribe using the `async` pipe which is the reactive approach:

```js
userName$!: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userName$ = this.myService.getName();
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="userName$ | async" as name>
  <h1>My name is {{ name }}</h1>
</ng-container>
```

I recommend taking a look at the official rxjs [docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)